# Error while using npm start in react js after cd react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

[image]

When I try to use npm start in vsCode terminal, it gaves an error that I've put it in picture above and as you can see in the picture my package.json just have start script in.
can anybody help me?

Comment: It doesn't suggest in [the NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/server) that it has a CLI script (not all packages do - is there anything in `./node_modules/.bin`?) and [this tutorial](https://serverjs.io/tutorials/getting-started/) suggests running it from a specific `index.js` file. It's not clear to me why you thought this would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, I recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

or remove full directory then 
run in you command line

```
npx create-react-app react-app
cd react-app
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything you see inside of "scripts' is what will be run when you type npm `script keyword here`.

`npm start` in your instance - is just running `server`. Which is not a command.

What you need to do is change the value from `server` to `node server.js` or `node your_file.js`.

Good luck on the learning adventure.